# std::string и std::initializer_list

Tags: c++

Есть невероятно простой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char* s1 = "A";
    const char* s2 = "B";
    std::string s{s1, s2};
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Компилируется "на ура". Но вот при его выполнении начинаются странности. Я ожидаю получить переменной `s` строку `"AB"`, но вместо этого получаю `"A"`. Более того, если при создании строки я поменяю местами параметры, т.е. напишу

```
std::string s{s2, s1};
```

то приложение вообще падает. И это происходит на двух компиляторах - MinGW 7.3.0 x64 и MSVC2017.

Ошибка при выполнении второго варианта (MinGW):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Ошибка, выдаваемая MSVC2017 маловразумительная.

Уважаемые гуру программирования! Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такое происходит? Вероятно, я делаю что-то неправильно, но что именно? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У std::string нет конструктора, принимающего набор си-строк. А именно так ты и пытаешься сделать.

Если тебе нужно создать строку из двух символов, то:

```
char s1 = 'A';                                                              
char s2 = 'B';                                                              
std::string s{s1, s2};
```

Если тебе нужно создать новую строку из конкатенации двух строк, то что-то типа:

```
const char* s1 = "A";                                                       
const char* s2 = "B";                                                       
std::string s = std::string("A") + std::string("B");
```

Comment: Почему код из вопроса вообще компилируется?

Answer (score 3):

Потому-что ты объявил 2 строки а как мы знаем на конце каждой строки есть терминирующий ноль `\0` он появляется неявно поэтому стоит использовать конкатенацию строк

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char* s1 = "A";
    const char* s2 = "B";
    std::string s = s1;
    s += s2;

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

}
```